# Node.js how to redirect URL to error if variable from database id in URL doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

as in the title,

How to redirect URL to error if variable from database id in URL doesn't exist
If I have:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('product/edit', { title: 'Express', id: req.params.id });
  //console.log(req.params.id); <--- return 4300030
});
```

If `req.params.id` does not exists in database how to make it redirect to error?

I wrote an example to show you what I mean:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile('baza.json', 'utf-8', function (error, content) {
    if (error) {
      res.json({
        error: error,
        status: false
      });
    } else {
      products = JSON.parse(content);
      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].id === req.body.id) {
          if (products[i].id === req.body.id) {
            res.render('product/edit', { title: 'Express', id: req.params.id });
          }
          else {
            res.render('error', { title: 'Error' });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Thanks
Btw I made two If same because I do not know what write in second.

Comment: what error are you getting?  Is it never redirected to an error.  The first issue I notice is ```req.body.id``` should be ```req.params.id```

Comment: Ok i corrected, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd8131048235ad21277b5a0523cef68e Problem is browser infinitely loads And there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you found the correct id, you want to stop successfully, if nothing found, you want to return an error:

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].id === req.params.id) {
        return res.render('product/edit', { title: 'Express', id: req.params.id });
    }
}
return res.render("error",{title:"Error"});
```